# Google Container Registry access denied when pushing docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I try to push my docker container to the google container registry, using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/?hl=fr#pushing_to_the_registry), but when I run

```
gcloud docker push b.gcr.io/my-bucket/image-name
```

I get the error :

```
The push refers to a repository [b.gcr.io/my-bucket/my-image] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Error: Status 403 trying to push repository my-bucket/my-image: "Access denied."
```

I couldn't find any more explanation (no -D, --debug, --verbose arguments were recognized), `gcloud auth list` and `docker info` tell me I'm connected to both services.

Anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to make sure the VM instance has enough access rights. You can set these at the time of **creating** the instance, or if you have already created the instance, you can also **edit** it (but first, you'll need to stop the instance). There are two ways to manage this access:

**Option 1**

Under the Identity and API access, select *Allow full access to all Cloud APIs*.

[image]

**Option 2 (recommended)**

Under the Identity and API access, select *Set access for each API* and then choose *Read Write* for Storage.

[image]

Note that you can also change these settings even after you have already created the instance. To do this, you'll first need to stop the instance, and then edit the configuration as mentioned above.

Comment: I just had to allow full access on all Cloud APIs. Thanks!

Comment: Had to spend a lot of time trying to debug this issue. Your solution to allow full access to the Cloud APIs finally solved it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `gsutil` to check the ACL to make sure you have permission to write to the bucket:

```
$ gsutil acl get gs://<my-bucket>
```

You'll need to check which group the account you are using is in ('owners', 'editors', 'viewers' etc.)

**EDIT**: I have experienced a very similar problem to this myself recently and, as @lampis mentions in his post, it's because the correct permission scopes were not set when I created the VM I was trying to push the image from. Unfortunately there's currently no way of changing the scopes once a VM has been created, so you have to delete the VM (making sure the disks are set to auto-delete!) and recreate the VM with the correct scopes ('compute-rw', 'storage-rw' seems sufficient). It doesn't take long though ;-).

See the `--scopes` section here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Comment: that's the problem : i'm in the owners group and the owners group members have owners rights on this bucket. Still access denied

Comment: And when you run `gcloud auth list`, the owner that you refer to definitely has `(active)` listed against it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, SO isn't sending me notifications.  Are you using Docker 1.7.0?  Docker made a breaking change in 1.7.0 to how they do authentication, but you should try a `gcloud components update`.  We updated the docs to include this too: https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/#access_denied

Comment: I ran into ACL issues, defining the SA user on the bucket ACL's fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I am seeing this but on an intermittent basis. e.g. I may get the error     denied: Permission denied for "latest" from request "/v2/...."., but when trying again it will work.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: In my case it actually turned out, I believe, to be a temporary issue in us-central1.

Comment: your comment saved my life. I've chosen another region to push and it worked instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me I forgot to prepend `gcloud` in the line (and I was wondering how `docker` would authenticate):

```
$ gcloud docker push <image>
```

Comment: this is outdated. gcloud provide auth for docker now.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal, run the code below

```
$ sudo docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://[HOSTNAME]
```

**Where**
-[HOSTNAME] is your container registry location (it is either gcr.io, us.gcr.io, eu.gcr.io, or asia.gcr.io). Check your tagged images to be sure by running `$ sudo docker images`).

If this doesn't fix it, try reviewing the VM's access scopes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker 1.7.0, there was a breaking change to how they handle authentication, which affects users who are using a mix of `gcloud docker` and `docker login`.

Be sure you are using the latest version of gcloud via: `gcloud components update`.

So far this seems to affect `gcloud docker`, `docker-compose` and other tools that were reading/writing the Docker auth file.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Depending on the OS you need to set the user rights accordingly. That means, if you're using `gcloud` without `sudo`, you need to make sure that you can also use the `docker` command without `sodo`. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/477554) for more info in case you're using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, the troubleshooting section from https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/#access_denied wasn't very helpful. I have Docker and GCloud full updated. Don't know what else to do.

BTW, I'm trying to push to "gcr.io".

Fixed. I was using a VM in compute engine as my development machine, and looks like I didn't give it enough rigths in Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **access denied** and I resolved it with creating new image using **Tag**:

```
docker tag IMAGE_WITH_ACCESS_DENIED gcr.io/my-project/my-new-image:test
```

After that I could **PUSH** It to Container registry:

```
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/my-project/my-new-image:test
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I also got this error inside Jenkins running on Google Kubernetes Engine when pushing the docker container. The reason was a node pool node version upgrade from 1.9.6-gke.1 to 1.9.7-gke.0 in gcp I did before. Worked again after the downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to gcloud from the machine you are:

```
gcloud auth login
```