# Workflow for building, pushing, and testing Docker images inside GKE / Kubernetes

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-shell

I am developing a Kubernetes service for deployment in Google Container Egine (GKE). Until recently, I have built Docker images in Google Cloud Shell, but I am hitting quota limits now, because the overall load on the free VM instance where Cloud Shell runs is apparently too high from multiple `docker build`s and `push`es. My experience so far is that after about a week or so of sustained work I face the following [error message](https://serverfault.com/questions/793364/hitting-maximum-usage-limits-in-cloud-shell-service-unavailable) and have to wait for about two days before the Cloud Shell becomes available again.

```
Service usage limits temporarily exceeded. Try connecting later.
```

I have tried to shift my `docker build`s and `push`es onto billable machines (GCE VM instances or GKE cluster nodes), but not to complete success:

- On a GCE VM instance, Docker is apparently not installed. (Also  makes sense.)
- On a GKE cluster node, Docker is installed and I can (`sudo`) `docker build` my image, but `docker push` (even after `gcloud docker`) fails with the following [error message](https://serverfault.com/questions/793364/hitting-maximum-usage-limits-in-cloud-shell-service-unavailable) after few seconds (after pushing a few layers): `denied: Access denied`

So what is a sustainable development workflow for docker images inside GKE? Am I supposed to install Docker on a VM instance (I hope not) or where else can I hope to `docker build`, `docker push` and ultimately `kubectl create` my service without running into work-stalling quota limits, etc.? (I am using a MacBook as local development machine, and would prefer not to install Docker there either, if I can help it. I.e. I prefer to build docker images in the Cloud.)

**UPDATE** If I equip a VM instance with a [Container-VM image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/vm-image/) as follows, `docker build` succeeds, but `docker push` fails just as on the GKE cluster node before (with `denied: Access denied`):

```
gcloud compute images list \
  --project google-containers \
  --no-standard-images
gcloud compute instances create tmp \
  --machine-type g1-small 
  --image container-vm-v20160321 \
  --image-project google-containers
  --zone europe-west1-d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925696/1789384) consisted of adding the scope `storage-rw` to the instance (otherwise `storage-r` applies by default):

```
gcloud compute images list \
  --project google-containers \
  --no-standard-images
gcloud compute instances create tmp \
  --machine-type g1-small \
  --image container-vm-v20160321 \
  --image-project google-containers \
  --zone europe-west1-d \
  --scopes compute-rw,storage-rw
```

In addition, I also had to install `kubectl` ([like so](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/prereqs/)) and configure it ([like so](https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html)), so overall this is quite a bite of a hassle. (Also the configuration will have to be updated when the cluster's endpoint changes e.g. after a recreation.)

But I can now use use a dedicated VM instance (such as `tmp`) for development work on Docker images.

**UPDATE** Added scope `compute-rw`, which is necessary e.g. for manipulating GCE addresses (as e.g. in `gcloud compute addresses list`).