# java.net.UnknownHostException in pid 1 for address resolved by kube-dns

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker, dns, kubernetes

I am receiving an `java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-service` on a machine where I can `ping postgres-service` on the command line. This is in the context of Kubernetes (more specifically GKE) services and Docker images. Could it be that Java requires additional packages (in comparison to `ping`) to be installed before it can resolve symbolic IP addresses such as `postgres-service`? I meanwhile guess the answer is no, and that the problem lies with resolving `postgres-service` via `kube-dns` is this particular situation (see UPDATE).

**UPDATE** The evidence (including the stacktrace below) suggests that the exception is triggered when Tomcat 9 tries to set-up a JDBC realm with `connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://postgres-service/mydb"`. The URL is configured in the context descriptor of a web app, which runs inside a Docker image derived from [`tomcat:9`](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/). The context descriptor is generated by a script configured as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`, which also starts Tomcat (just like the original `tomcat:9` does), i.e. the last few lines of the `Dockerfile` look as follows:

```
COPY tomcat-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "/tomcat-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I can `ping postgres-service` after entering a shell with `kubectl exec -it <image> bash`. Could it be that Tomcat (when run as the image's "single process" with pid 1 by way of the Dockerfile's `CMD`) sees a different DNS configuration than `bash` that runs at its sibling? The actual [DNS configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build/kube-dns) employs `kube-dns`, as is apparent from `/etc/resonf.conf`.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:661)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5054)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-service
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: It depends on your name resolution configuration. Also, what code triggers this exception?

Comment: @fge I've added more information re the code that triggers the execption. The name resolution configuration is provided by Kubernetes 1.3, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You say that in /etc/resolv.conf you have an entry for kube-dns; can you resolve the address of this server from your VM/container/whatever?

Comment: @fge Yep, e.g. by executing `ping postgres-service` from inside the other pod.

Comment: I was not talking about this, sorry for the misinterpretation; I was wondering whether you could resolve the address of `kube-dns` itself. It may be that the `ping` program and Java use a different name configuration.

Comment: @fge The pod's `/etc/resolve.conf` refers to a nameserver by a numeric IP address. `nslookup` indicates this IP address is equivalent to `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.localkube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.` Thx for your support.

Comment: Glad to see you solved your problem... The FQDN of that machine is very strange though (looks like `kube-system.svc.cluster` is "duplicated").

Comment: @fge Sorry, I mistyped. It is actually `kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using a VM instance without scope `compute-rw` for development so far (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972533/1789384)). I've now recreated it including that scope and rebuilt all relevant Docker images there. Apparently this has resolved the issue.

**UPDATE** There was also a second issue in that I had `clusterIP: None` as part of the service specification of `postgres-service` (now gone). It beats me why I was still able to `ping postgres-service` from another pod in the same cluster.