# Google Container Registry: push reports "Repository does not exist"

Tags: docker, google-container-registry

I have build a docker image in Google Cloud Shell and now want to push it into Google Container Registry (GCR). I receive the following error messages:

```
$ sudo docker push eu.gcr.io/<project>/<image>
The push refers to a repository [eu.gcr.io/<project>/<image>] (len: 0)
Repository does not exist: eu.gcr.io/<project>/<image>
```

Yet I can see the very repository and its content in Google Cloud Console (i.e. inside the same browser window as Google Cloud Shell) and this has also worked before. I have also previously executed `gcloud docker` for authentication.

What could be wrong and how can I successfully push the Docker image into GCR?

Comment: that's an awesome avatar there @Drux

Comment: @the0ther "Me like cookies and good answers! Yumm."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reverted to using a [dedicated VM instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38971385/1789384) (instead of Google Cloud Shell) for building and pushing images. This makes the problem go away.

Answer (score 1):

Drux:

If you are still interested in figuring out what is wrong when you use Google Cloud Shell, please let me know and we can try to investigate. your symptom usually means some local problem instead of a server side problem,  though anything is possible.

Comment: I appreciate the follow up, and my come back on your offer later on.